# Why can the set of all natural numbers and omega be put in one-to-one correspondence with natural numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

If $\omega$ comes literally after we've run out of all natural numbers, then why can the set of all natural numbers and omega be put in one-to-one correspondence with natural numbers? I feel  the existence of $\omega$ is somewhat contradictory for this reason. Please explain.

Comment: What is $\omega$ and what do you mean by "after we've run out of all natural numbers"?

Comment: What are "natural numbers" for you? Do they staet with $0$ or $1$?

Comment: Define the following corerspondence : $c : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N \cup \{ \omega \}$. Let $c(0)= \omega$ and $c(n)=n-1$ for $n > 0$.

Comment: There's no *order-preserving* correspondence, but as Mauro's comment shows, you can put $\omega$ first (for example).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I think your comment should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: I don't understand if the question is really about $\omega$ or $\omega+1$.

Comment: See [Ordinals and cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Ordinals_and_cardinals) : "Each ordinal associates with one cardinal, its cardinality. If there is a bijection between two ordinals (e.g. $ω=1+ω$ and $ω+1>ω$), then they associate with the same cardinal."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two distinct notions that are relevant here:

- Sets
- Ordered sets

When you talk about "$\omega$ coming after the natural numbers", you are talking about *ordered* sets — specifically, the ordered set $\omega + 1$. (the underlying set of $\omega + 1$ is is $\mathbb{N} \cup \{ \omega \}$)

There does not exist an *order-preserving* bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\omega+1$.

When you talk about "$\omega+1$ can be put into one-to-one correspondence with natural numbers", you are talking about *sets*.

There does exist a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and (the underlying set of) $\omega + 1$. But by the above remarks, no such bijection can be order-preserving. As mentioned in the comments, an easy-to-consider bijection is the following correspondence:

$$ \begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \ldots
\\ \updownarrow &\updownarrow &\updownarrow &\updownarrow &
\\ \omega & 0 & 1 & 2 & \ldots
\end{matrix} $$

See how it doesn't preserve order: we've corresponded $0 \leftrightarrow \omega$ and $1 \leftrightarrow 0$, but as to the ordering on these two sets we have $0<1$ and $\omega > 0$.

Comment: Why does order preserving not matter when determining cardinality? The sets $\omega+1$ and N have the same number of elements (by the accepted definition of cardinality). But isn't $\omega$, by definition, an extra element added to the set of natural numbers?